# How do I view comments on my own deleted questions?

Tags: feature-request

I would at least appreciate being able to see the full text of the feedback I receive on my deleted questions—it makes me less likely to post questions that will end up getting deleted the next time.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Everything you need to know about asking questions that will be accepted by the community can be found at [sitename].com/question/how-to-ask.  Example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, this has been asked before.  You're SOL.  If you have a link to the question, I can get the comment for you manually though.

Comment: Oh sorry - this is a PSE question - I can't access it then, but if you post a link to the question, some other 10K PSE user might be nice enough to grab the comment for you

Comment: @AdamRackis: Actually, I'm not sure which site the example is from...

Comment: There aren't [any users in the CogSci.SE private beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2149/cognitive-sciences) with the [1k reputation required to view deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) yet.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Well, there are [some users](http://api.cogsci.stackexchange.com/1.1/users/moderators) that might help out anyway